# Is the thecal sac ectoderm?

Tags: neuroscience, anatomy, embryology

The [thecal sac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thecal_sac), or dural sac, is the membranous sheath of *dura mater* that surrounds the spinal cord and the cauda equina. The thecal sac contains the cerebrospinal fluid in which the spinal cord 'floats'.

Is the dura matter ectoderm? I know neural crest and such is ectoderm. But the meninges, in particular the dura, where do they come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *dura mater* is formed by the [mesoderm](http://www.medbullets.com/step1-embryology/3004/germ-layer-derivatives). The mesoderm is the middle layer of the early trilaminar embryo. The three germ layers are the ectoderm, mesoderm and endoderm, formed by gastrulation. The middle germ layer forms **connective tissues** and **muscle** throughout the body, with the exception of the head region, where some of these structures have a neural crest (ectoderm) origin. Connective tissues include cartilage, bone, blood, blood vessel endothelium and dermis, but also the *dura mater*. The muscles include cardiac, skeletal and smooth muscle (fig. 1).

[image: germ layers]
<sup>Fig. 1. Germ layers. Source: [UNSW](https://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php/Mesoderm)</sup>

<sub>**Source**

**-** [UNSW](https://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php/Mesoderm)</sub>